# MVC datetime list not saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple MVC4 model that adds a `DateTime.Now` to a `List<DateTime>()` list.

However when I do an `EntityState.Modified`, the changes are not being kept. 
I've debugged this by modifying another property in the model and that saves fine.

So I really am at a loss as to why this is not saving. If anyone has any ideas as to why its not saving that would be life saver material:

The Model:

```
public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PageURL { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Visits { get; set; }

    public Page()
    {
      Visits = new List<DateTime>();
    }

}
```

Here's my code:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

   public ActionResult CookiePolicy()
   {
        var page = db.Pages.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PageURL == "cookiepolicy");

        page.Visits.Add(DateTime.Now); // this list of datetime objects does not get updated
        page.Title = "test "; //but this property does
        ViewBag.Title = page.Title;

        db.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View(page);
    }
```

Comment: What is db?  I don't see it declared within the function.

Comment: db is the ApplicationDbContext, I've updated the code to reflect that

Comment: Added the model as well

Comment: I appear to be missing ASP.NET stuff after I upgraded to VS2015, once I fix it hopefully I can take a look at what is going on.

Comment: collection of primitive types (like int, DateTime, bool) are not supported

Comment: @FabioLuz Do you have any reference for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Fabio Luz mentioned in his comment primitive type collections aren't supported. A collection within an class retrieved from a context is generally assumed to represent a One-to-Many / Many-to-Many relationship.

When building models keep in mind how they would be represented in a SQL table, and having a column that has a collection within is not supported in such a structure. Now, if you were referencing another object (table) than the object (table record) would have certain properties, such as a primary key etc.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Here is a sample model you might want to consider:

```
public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PageURL { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueriable<Visit> Visits { get; set; }    
}

public class Visit
{
    // ...  properties related to data you wish to retain about the visit
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; } // navigation property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit** Fabio Luz mentioned:
>
> "collection of primitive types (like int, DateTime, bool) are not
>   supported"
>
> So the solution below seems like the right option.

Ok, so after some deliberation. I decided to create a new model called vist and have this as the list instead of datetime:

```
public class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public BrowserType BrowserType { get; set; }
    public String Duration { get; set; }

    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }

    public Visit()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        BrowserType = BrowserType.Other;
    }
}
```

There are benefits to this. Now I can store more information then just the datetime.

So for anyone who had the same problem as me. Consider pushing it out into its own model for greater flexibility.